# Laravel Passport: create token with custom username and password

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

In my application, I am username as email or phone number. so username can be email or phone number. But laravel passport accepts username as email. And I want to generate password grant type token with email and password or phone_no and password.
so required values to generate token will be

1. email/password
2. phone_no/password
   How can I generate token with phone_no as username?

Comment: go to \vendor\laravel\passport\src\pridge\UserRepository.php path go to function getUserEntityByUserCredentials and add phone_no to $user eloquent as OrWhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use findForPassport method in user model . Like below

```
class User  extends Authenticatable {

        use HasApiTokens;
    
        public function findForPassport($username) {
            return self::firstWhere('email', $username) ?? self::firstWhere('phone_no',  $username);
        }

 }
```

Also you can read this document https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#customizing-the-username-field